# Cflags in NDK-build

Tags: android, android-ndk

I found that using ndk-build to build an libxxx.so doesn't need -fPIC in LOCAL_CFLAGS. Does that mean that position-independent code isn't necessary for android or that -fPIC is concealed as a default option which you don't need to add again or something else like that? What's the truth?

Comment: _"or that -fPIC is concealed as a default option which you don't need to add again or something else like that?"_ That would be quite easy to test: just add `LOCAL_CFLAGS += -v` to your Android.mk to see the build commands as they are executed.

Comment: @Michael That really works, thanks a lot. I found that the lowercase "-fpic" is the default option for NDK compiler, which means ndk-build create a faster and conciser object file than the one with option -fPIC.

Comment: -fPIC only applies to executables, not to shared libraries.  See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/application_mk.html for more information.